# How to retrieve the same value from a dynamically changing text file using PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, explode

I'm trying to retrieve a value from the same 'column' in a text file from a website which changes daily.  I'm having difficulty as the values are not in the same places each day and sometimes a value is present and sometimes it's not.

For example, I'm after the value in '12hMx', day 1 it's:

```
       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom                      
03002                      10.6  13.4   6.8             Baltasound
```

on day 2, it's:

```
       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom                      
03002         14.5               12.8   7.5             Baltasound
```

on day 3, it's:

```
       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom                      
03002                      10.1         5.5             Baltasound
```

I'm using PHP file_get_contents() and then explode() to get the values between 03002 and Baltasound but obviously they change day on day.

Is there a sure fire way to always get the value for 12hMx irrespective of the values preceding it?

My current code, which is inconsistent:

```
$forecastPage = file_get_contents("http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~brugge/CURR.html");
            $pageArray = explode('Little Rissington', $forecastPage, 8);

    if (sizeof($pageArray) > 1) {

            $secondPageArray = explode('03658', $pageArray[1]);

                          if (sizeof($secondPageArray) > 1) {

                $weather = $secondPageArray[0];
                $lessWeather = explode('  ',$weather);
                $wetness = $lessWeather[43];
                $totalrain = $lessWeather[10];
                $totalsun = $lessWeather[46];
```

"Little Rissington" and "03658" are the text items immediately before and after the line I'm interested in.

Comment: how are the columns delimited? tabs? And if you show your existing code it will be easier to spot any processing mistakes.

Comment: The delimiter seems to be spaces (whitespace)

Comment: well, is the 12hMx value (or the space where it would be) always the same number of characters from the start of the line? If so, you can retrieve it easily. If not, it's going to be very tricky.

Comment: Yes.  Same number of characters.

Comment: and sorry, is the value always the same length and format? e.g. it's always in the format xx.x with exactly 4 characters in total? If so, then you just get to the line you want in the file, fetch the line as a single string, and then use a substring function to extract the number of characters you want from the known position in the string.

Comment: You can do something like accessing line array style, then searching values based on : $mean = get_text_between(0, strpos($line1, 'high'), etc ... no ?

Comment: appears to be same length and format, yes.

Comment: just curious: It may assist if you show the HTML source code from the web-browser for those two lines? Please add it to your question. Please don't post the HTML as a comment. Could we look at the website or is a login required?

Comment: The website is http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~brugge/Jun2016.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I just expressed my think about this, while the headers stay the same in your console output, I guess this method would work. By the way please keep in mind that's only a proof of concept, it's not optimized, and surely not optimal. You will have to review it before using in production. Also not secured, not done for UTF-8 support etc ... Keep it in mind ;)

So the code is the following :

```
$consoleOuput = '       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom                      
03002                      10.6  13.4   6.8             Baltasound';

/*$consoleOuput = '       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom
03002         14.5               12.8   7.5             Baltasound';*/

/*$consoleOuput = '       mean   high    low  Total 12hMx  Max Temp Anom
03002                      10.1         5.5             Baltasound';*/

list($headers, $data) = explode(PHP_EOL, $consoleOuput);

$meanPos  = array( 0                        , strpos($headers, 'high' ) );
$highPos  = array( strpos($headers, 'high' ), strpos($headers, 'low'  ) );
$lowPos   = array( strpos($headers, 'low'  ), strpos($headers, 'Total') );
$totalPos = array( strpos($headers, 'Total'), strpos($headers, '12hMx') );
$hMxPos   = array( strpos($headers, '12hMx'), strpos($headers, 'Max'  ) );
$maxPos   = array( strpos($headers, 'Max'  ), strpos($headers, 'Temp' ) );
$tempPos  = array( strpos($headers, 'Temp' ), strpos($headers, 'Anom' ) );
$anomPos  = array( strpos($headers, 'Anom' ), strlen($headers         ) );


$get = function($pos) use ($data)
{
    list($start, $stop) = $pos;

    $res = substr($data, $start, $stop - $start);

    $res = trim($res);

    return $res;
};

$mean  = $get($meanPos);
$high  = $get($highPos);
$low   = $get($lowPos);
$total = $get($totalPos);
$hMx   = $get($hMxPos);
$max   = $get($maxPos);
$temp  = $get($tempPos);
$anom  = $get($anomPos);

$res = array(
    'mean'  => $mean,
    'high'  => $high,
    'low'   => $low,
    'Total' => $total,
    '12hMx' => $hMx,
    'Max'   => $max,
    'Temp'  => $temp,
    'Anom'  => $anom,
);

print_r($res);
```

You can see I'm starting with exploding the data into to vars : `$headers` and `$data`.

Then I'm finding start and stop of each column in header row. And then using it to gather text in the data row. Then I simply put it into array. The tow steps can be merged but well, I was not sure of the output I would like to get before coding it so .. :p

I'm up for any question about this.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you.  I ran this and got the following:  Array ( [mean] => 03002 [high] => [low] => [Total] => 10.6 [12hMx] => 13.4 [Max] => 6.8 [Temp] => [Anom] => ).  So the concept works...I'll go throught it and try to understand it and make any tweaks.

Comment: Well, while your columns headers have a defined width (which is from the start of the word defining them to the start of the next column in most cases) you can simply get those sizes, and then cut the next line at those sizes which will give you the correct array :)